# Output of `iw list`: phy_x corresponds to what interface?

Tags: command-line, wifi, network-interface, wlan

I have 2 interfaces wlan0 and wlan1.

When I want to see the modes that support my cards I do `iw list` and I see phy0 and phy2. How do I know what information corresponds to what card?

In other words, how can I know what wlan_x corresponds to which phy_x?

Comment: *graphics* card? I'm sure you meant something different...

Answer (score 2):

With

```
iw dev
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I suggest explain more, what it does and why.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on this a bit for another project:

List wifi interfaces:

```
iw dev | grep -Po '^\sInterface\s\K.*$'
```

List connected SSID's:

```
iw dev | grep -Po '^\sInterface\s\K.*$' | xargs -I {} iw dev {} link | grep -Po '^\sSSID:\s\K.*$'
```